# push_back(move(struct.unique_ptr)) causes compile errors

Tags: c++, struct, unique-ptr

I have a function which is like

```
for (auto&& i : v) {
    ...
    this->fifoQueue.push_back(move(i.p));
    ...
}
```

where `fifoQueue` is of type `vector<unique_ptr<T> >`, `v` is of type `vector<struct s>`, and `struct s` is

```
struct s {
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<T> p;
    ...
};
```

The statement `this->fifoQueue.push_back(move(i.p));` has caused a compiler error "`... error: declared here unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete; ...`". What's wrong with this statement?

I have another working statement basically the same as it, except that statement is like `this->fifoQueue.push_back(move(p))`. So `i.p` is the evil? Or `auto&&`?

---

Update:

As Petr inferred, `v` is indeed a `const` reference, which caused the error.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please....

Comment: Are you sure that `v` in your first code is not `const`? And that there is no other place from where `i.p`can become `const`?

Comment: Just curious, what about `this->fifoQueue.push_back(move(i).p)`?

Comment: Holy... Yeah, `v` is `const`. My bad. Have been staying up and now a little dizzy. Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6780311ab8ed83f6) doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 3):

(Expanding my comment)

Your error message, `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&)`, seems to indicate that `i.p` becomes `const`, thus `push_back` has to make its copy (or in fact even `std::move` has to make its copy, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28595207/3216312)). However, `unique_ptr` can not be constructed as a copy of `const unique_ptr&`, because this is absolutely senseless given the nature of `unique_ptr`. So you should look where does it become `const` from.

I thought the most probable source of this `const`ness is from `v`, because you have not shown us that declaration.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, seems like compiler wants to make a copy of your struct. Because of this `unique_ptr` inside it cannot.

When you think about it, gues what would mean `auto` here? It would be rather `yourStruct &` than `yourStruct`, because you can actually modify the struct inside this `vector`. And bacause of [reference collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2) you get `yourStruct &` from `auto &&`.

All in all, instead of thinking how to avoid this situation with `push_back` simply use `emplace_back` which enforces construction inside vector.