# What do we call a constructor like this C::C(const C&&)? And is there any use of it other than prohibit move from const?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I can have declaration of three constructors like

- copy constructor `C::C(const C&)`
- move constructor `C::C(C&&)`
- `C::C(const C&&)`

in a class without ambiguity.

What do we call a constructor like `C::C(const C&&)`? Does it have some kind of nickname?

I can come up with `=delete` to explicitly prohibit users from unknowingly trying to move from `const` and restricting the automatic copy fallback effect. This reminds users what they are doing.

And is there any other use of it?

Comment: This signature also qualifies for the name "move constructor".

Comment: It is valid syntax but is useless as you can't move from a const object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28595415/1460794

Comment: Why is it wrong if the user of your class tries to move from a `const` object?

Comment: @KABoissonneault user can try - he will not succeed. To move from means to modify the object. You cannot modify const object

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Yeah, is that a problem for this object?

Comment: @KABoissonneault When `C::C(const C&&)` is not declared, `C(std::move(aConstCObj))` matches the copy constructor "automatically silently". So users might be thinking they benefit from move semantics, which is not true. [wandbox.org/permlink/pLJk6HrG2DofpTrh](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pLJk6HrG2DofpTrh)

Comment: @sandthorn Does your client care? The only way I could see this turning into an error is if they expect, for example, iterators to be transferred to the other object in `std::vector`. Otherwise, it's either just a performance penalty (maybe) or a compile error if there's no copy constructor.

Comment: @KABoissonneault You have a point. However, when one cares to `move`, wouldn't he or she care about performance? I just think if they care, we should do too.

Comment: @sandthorn I am just not a fan of restricting your interface for needs your client _may_ or may not have. Sounds like a recipe for issues on github when you break your client's templates. If they care about performance, they will take the precautions they need

Comment: @KABoissonneault That's also good point. I guess I'm now convinced on _not_ `=delete`. Because I guess that const-ness should always be very obvious to performance savvy users after all. Thanks.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/a/28595117/#28596435](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28595117/#28596435) : "ability for generic code to be resilient" so you really need that kind of fallback very bad.

Answer (score 6):

```
C::C(C const&&);
```

is what I call a const-qualified move constructor.

It informs the constructor that it (A) is coming from a discarded object, and (B) you are not allowed to mutate non-const components of the source object (as the object may actually be `const`, in which case mutating them is undefined behavior).

In the event that `C` contains `mutable` state, that state may be safely moved-from in some cases.  In the event that it does not, it behaves much like a `const&`, unless the components of `C` have their own `const&&` move constructors.

In other circumstances, you may want to `=delete` it.  I personally wouldn't.

Comment: Hadn't thought of the mutable members. That is a reasonable use case.

Comment: @Yakk I think it should have a short nickname. Moreover, wouldn't 'const-qualified' suggest that the constructor might behave like const member function? I think it would be more confusing with that word.

Comment: @sandthorn No, short names are important when something is often talked about.  The situations where this move constructor is worth bothering with are narrow and obscure.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/a/28595117/#28596435](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28595117/#28596435) : "ability for generic code to be resilient" : You don't really want to `=delete` it because you really want the copy fallback.