# C++ unique_ptr rvalue passing using std::move not working

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy of 'unique_ptr<Searchable>'                                                                      
unique_ptr<Searchable> current(std::move(searchSpace.top()));
```

Hello,

I am trying to figure out why this doesn't compile. Search space is priority queue and I am trying to move rvalue searchSpace.top() to new current object.

Strangely enough, If I change priority queue to deque :

```
        unique_ptr<Searchable> current(std::move(Q.front()));
```

This worked fine when Q is deque.

So why is the latter one working not the first one?

rest of the error message:

```
 copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'unique_ptr<Searchable,
  std::__1::default_delete<Searchable> >' has a user-declared move
  constructor
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& __u) _NOEXCEPT
```

Comment: You are missing a [mcve]. There's no way for us to know what your code is unless you show it to us.

Comment: `priority_queue::top` returns a `const&` to the element

Comment: I think I supplied more than enough information for this question. I was asking a general question why a member of certain data structure can be moved while others cannot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation of std::priority_queue::top()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/top)

> const_reference top() const;

it returns const reference, which by `std::move` would be converted to `const T &&` . On another side `const T &&` is not accepted by move ctor of `std::unqiue_ptr`, as it does not have such overload, it only accepts `T &&` (without `const`) see [documentation of std::unqiue_ptr ctors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr)

On why const reference is accepted by `std::move` see here [Why can we use `std::move` on a `const` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595117/why-can-we-use-stdmove-on-a-const-object)

Answer (score 1):

`std::priority_queue::top()` only has a `const` overload returning a `const` reference. This cannot be moved from.

`std::deque::front()` on the other hand has const and non-const overloads returning equally qualified references. You seem to be using the non-const overload, the result of which can be moved from.