# Why does C++ make the element type of std::initializer_list const?

Tags: c++, c++14, standards, rvalue-reference

I commonly use `std::initializer_list<std::string>`, say `{"foo"s, "bar"s}`, to fill a container.

Obviously, `std::initializer_list<std::string>` contains temporary strings, and I can move them into a container:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std::literals;    

void f(std::initializer_list<std::string> il)
{
    std::list<std::string> coll;
    for (auto&& tmp_str : il)
    {
        coll.emplace_back(std::move(tmp_str)); // Why ok here?
    }
}

int main()
{
    f({"foo"s, "bar"s});
}
```

However, according to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> An object of type std::initializer_list is a lightweight proxy
>   object that provides access to an array of objects of type const T.

**Why does C++ make the element type of std::initializer_list const?**

Comment: `std::initializer_list` doesn't interact with move semantics at all. It is kind of broken like this. There have been proposals to fix it, e.g. [P0065R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0065r0.pdf). From that proposal's text it seems that `std::initializer_list` was developed concurrently with move semantic and unification attempts were too late for inclusion in C++11 and it seems that because of the way it is designed now unification in a backwards-compatible way is not straight-forward.

Comment: If you consider move semantics non-existent, then there is no reason not to make the elements `const`. They would need to be copied from anyway and making them `const` gives the compiler additional guarantees for optimization.

Comment: Please note that your code is not valid C++11. The `std::literals::operator""s` was introduced only in C++14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Obviously, `std::initializer_list<std::string>` contains temporary strings*

Does it, though? It is allowed to be implemented it as a thin proxy. In which case it would refer to the original instances `"foo"s`, `"bar"s`.

> *... and I can move them into a container*

I doubt that. `std::move()` of a `const` lvalue-reference produces... a `const` rvalue-reference. That won't quite match a move-constructor as a viable candidate.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "A()\n"; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout << "A(&&)\n"; }
    A(A const&) { std::cout << "A(const&)\n"; }
};

int main() {
    const A a;
    A b(std::move(a));
}
```

Prints

```
A()
A(const&)
```

MSVC 2019 even warns:

```
Warning C26478  Don't use std::move on constant variables. (es.56).
```

See also [Why can we use `std::move` on a `const` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595117/why-can-we-use-stdmove-on-a-const-object)

Comment: At least since C++14 is is specified that the elements of the `std::initializer_list` form an array of type `T` and are copy-initialized from the the initializer list elements, so they cannot refer to the original objects, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list.

Comment: @walnut the question is tagged [tag:c++11]. And C++14 also says "*The implementation is free to allocate the array in read-only memory*"

Comment: I do not really understand this hammering MSVC warning since `T const&&` is produced in the first "step" as demanded by the standard. The warning would make sense if there is no target constructor for this quite strange type but then the warning message itself should be more specific about that.